# React with Google Chromes Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, google-chrome-headless, puppeteer

Trying to **render a react component** with [chrome puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues)
 running on my Node.js environment I’m having following problem:

- logging `element` gives me in the *headless chrome* console: `console.log(element)` => `<div id="test-wrapper"></div>`
- `testWrapper` in the terminal `console.log(testWrapper)` => `{}`

  ```
  puppeteer.launch().then(async browser => {

      const page = await browser.newPage();

      const testDocumentPath = path.resolve('./lib/components/util/testDocument.html');
      await page.goto(`file://${testDocumentPath}`);

      const testWrapper = await page.evaluate((selector) => {
          const element = document.querySelector(selector);
          console.log(element);

          return element;
      }, '#test-wrapper');

      console.log(testWrapper);
  });
  ```

So trying to do …

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <div>{':)'}</div>,
    testWrapper
);
```

… obviously results in an error `(node:90555) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Invariant Violation: _registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element.`

I feel like even if I manage to get the DOM element I’m missing something here to inject a react application.

Comment: What's present in the testDocument.html? Does it have all the prerequisites for rendering a react app? If so, you should render it in the evaluate function, not outside of it (where console.log(testWrapper)) is now.

Comment: maybe making minimalist  repository to reproduce the error, will give an ease to examine the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.evaluate` does not return a dom element. And, you are trying to modify the elements in different context. The page in the browser window and the context you have in your nodeJS is absolutely different.

Here is a different way to deal with React and Puppeteer.
First, I have an entry file where I export the function to window.

By doing this, I can access it from the browsers context easily. Instead of window, you can actually export it and try expose-loader and so on. I'll use webpack to build it.

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

function Hello() {
  return <h1>Hello from React</h1>;
}

function renderIt(domNode) {
  render(<Hello />, domNode);
}

window.renderIt = renderIt;
```

On the webpack config,

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

const loaders = [
  {
    test: /\.jsx?$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    query: {
      presets: ['babel-preset-es2015', 'babel-preset-react'],
      plugins: []
    }
  }
];

module.exports = {
  entry: './entry.js',
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    libraryTarget: 'umd'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: loaders
  }
};
```

Now whenever I run webpack, it'll create a bundle.js file for me. Now let's have a puppeteer file,

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://github.com');
  await page.addScriptTag({ path: require.resolve('./bundle.js') });
  await page.evaluate(() => {
    renderIt(document.querySelector('div.jumbotron.jumbotron-codelines > div > div > div > h1'));
  });
  await page.screenshot({ path: 'example.png' });
  await browser.close();
})();
```

As you can see, I'm using the renderIt function that I exposed to window earlier. And when I run it, here is the result,

[image]

Sweet! Hello from react :)

Oh! And if it fails to execute script on the page due to CORS issue, you can inject it instead using the old injectFile function, until they fix their addScriptTag function, or remove deprecation from injectFile.

```
/**
 * injects file to puppeteer page context
 * @param  {Object} page     context where to execute the script
 * @param  {String} filePath path of specific script
 * @return {Promise}         Injects content to page context
 */
const fs = require('fs');

async function injectFile(page, filePath) {
  let contents = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
      if (err) return reject(err);
      resolve(data);
    });
  });
  contents += `//# sourceURL=` + filePath.replace(/\n/g, '');
  return page.mainFrame().evaluate(contents);
}

// usage: await injectFile(page, require.resolve('FILE PATH'));
// export it if you want to keep things seperate
```

Comment: So what is the proper way to deal with puppeteer and react? As far as I understand I have two options: a) pass a url that renders a react page to puppeteer or b) pass a react component as html (ReactDOMServer.renderToString(element)) to puppeteer. I have some complex login logic that I'd like to avoid, so option a) is not preferred. With option b) I run into the problem that required things from componentDidMount are not run server side anymore (that cannot be moved to componentWillMount).... Any advice on this?

Comment: What are you trying to make exactly?

Comment: There, updated the actual answer with real working example.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! What I'm trying to do: screenshot my own react page in puppeteer, but because of the complex login requirements I would like to take a shortcut by rendering the componen to html (with ReactDOMServer.renderToString(element)) and then passing that to puppeteer (await page.setContent(html)), but as I said I ran into the problem that componentDidMount() isn't run with that approach... so I was hoping there were some more tricks to this :/

Comment: Posted it as new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48034767/is-it-possible-to-pass-a-react-component-to-puppeteer