# Pass class as parameter to nightmare evaluate

Tags: javascript, typescript, mocha.js, electron, nightmare

Passing `class` as parameter to access static methods. The [Evaluate](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare#evaluatefn-arg1-arg2) doesn't seems to pass it as it should. I've debugged this [line](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare/blob/master/lib/actions.js#L547) that seems to have the valid arguments but when I call the `resolve method` inside  then it throws error

> Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined

The class just contains simple static method as

```
class App { 
    public static resolve() { return true }; 
}
```

The test is as follows

```
//abc.test.ts
it('should contain "abc" text in Href', (done) => {
        nightmare
            .goto("abc.com")
            .evaluate((driver: any) => {
                console.log('driver', driver.resolve()); also is there a way to console.log in evaluate?
                return document.getElementById("a").textContent;
            }, App)
            .end()
            .then((response: any) => {
                expect(response).to.have.containIgnoreSpaces("abc");
                done();
            })
            .catch((error: any) => console.log("Error", error));
    });
```

The npm command to run tests

```
set DEBUG=nightmare && mocha --recursive --require jsdom-global/register --require ts-node/register --require babel-core/register tests/*
```

Answer (score 0):

Evaluate will stringify everything and you will lose your class or any kind of function.

This [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48035638/6161265) is an answer for another library called Puppeteer, but it will come handy for your nightmare script too.

And you should